# How to make a post using WATSON and Node js?

Tags: node.js, post, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I want to make a POST (add a new task) through chatting with Watson.

I have the POST function which works very well, I tested it on Postman. And I have the Watson nodes created.

Here is my endpoint from the POST in Node js:

```
MainRouter.post('/welcome', (req, res) => {
    TaskPost.postTask(req.body).then(message => {
        return res.json(message);
    }).catch((error) => {
        return res.status(404).json(error);
    });
});
```

Here is my conversation with Watson (is working very well):

[image]

I also included this in the main.js and changed the password and url:

```
const AssistantV2 = require('ibm-watson/assistant/v2');
const { IamAuthenticator } = require('ibm-watson/auth');

const assistant = new AssistantV2({
  authenticator: new IamAuthenticator({ apikey: '<apikey>' }),
  serviceUrl: 'https://api.us-south.assistant.watson.cloud.ibm.com',
  version: '2018-09-19'
});
```

How do I make this connection ? What do I have to include?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend the [official Node.js SDK for the IBM Watson services](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk/). It includes support for Watson Assistant and is easy to use.

If you still want to use the V2 API directly, then take a look at [how the SDK utilizes the API](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk/blob/master/assistant/v2.ts). As alternative, the [API docs for Watson Assistant have code snippets for Node.js](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant/assistant-v2?code=node).

The basic flow is that you authenticate, then establish a session, and finally [send messages](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant/assistant-v2?code=node#message) with the user input to Watson Assistant.

To get to your dialog node with the task, the user (or your code) would need to send the right intents and entities for navigating from the root node to that specific subnode.